# Exposing a service on EKS using NGINX ingress and issues with load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am trying to set up a service and expose it externally on EKS. I have already done it on GKE pretty easily but now AWS is giving me a hard time.

My NGINX yaml looks something like that:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.mydomain.com
    secretName: myapp-tls
  rules:
  - host: app.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-service
          servicePort: 80
```

And then I have my domain `app.mydomain.com` on Google Domains pointing at the ingress external address. There is also a cert-manager service running in order to support HTTPS.

However, while basically the same setup worked completely out of the box on GKE, EKS gives me a hard time.

From what I understand it has something to do with EKS default LoadBalancer being layer 4 in comparison to Google's layer 7 (Which explains HTTPS not working) but there is also issues with redirections of the domain as it just resolves as the ingress address instead of my desired address and thus my app doesn't show up.

The domain is registered over Google Domains and I'm creating Synthetic Records (for my subdomain) that points to my ingress external address on EKS. The same scheme works perfectly fine on GKE but here it resolves the address as the ingress address instead of my domain which results in 404 on the ingress side.

I was wondering if someone could please point me to how to properly set it up? Should I give up on nginx ingress on EKS and move onto ALB? and how to properly associate the domain?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

#### Edit:

output of `kubectl describe ingress myapp-ingress`:

```
Name:             myapp-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          ********************************-****************.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  myapp-tls terminates app.mydomain.com
Rules:
  Host                          Path  Backends
  ----                          ----  --------
  app.mydomain.com  
                                /   myapp-service:80 (172.31.2.238:8000)
Annotations:                    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: myapp-letsencrypt-prod
                                kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:                         <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I give up on nginx ingress on EKS and move onto ALB

No.  NGinX ingress controllers work perfectly well on EKS.  It is possible to configure them as either layer 4 or layer 7; we use it in layer 7 mode.

Can you update your question with the output of

```
kubectl get ingress myapp-ingress
```

I think your ingress path is also incorrect. Unless I'm mistaken that's just routing the root of your app, not all uris.  We use the scheme

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: service.d.tld
      http:
      paths:
        - path: /?(.*)  # <--- 
          backend:
            serviceName: my-service
            servicePort: http
```

Are you seeing errors in the nginx ingress controller's logs?  That + `kubectl events` are both useful for debugging purposes.

I'd disable TLS everywhere and get your service working on http, then work stepwise on getting TLS enabled on the ingress controller.

Edit:  Based on your response above,

```
curl -H "Host: app.mydomain.com" http://<elb-address>:80
```

SHOULD call through to your service behind the ingress.

How is app.mydomain.com defined?  Is it a CNAME to the  dns entry?

Comment: Thank for the response! I've updated my original post with the output of `describe` instead of `get` as I felt it would be more detailed. regarding the `/` and `/?(.*)` - My yaml is basically a copy-paste of my yaml from GKE where everything works perfectly so unless there is a difference between GKE and EKS I would believe that it should work

Comment: In response to your edit (Will also update the original):
The domain is registered over Google Domains and I'm creating Synthetic Records that points to my ingress external address on EKS. The same scheme works perfectly fine on GKE but here it resolves the address as the ingress address instead of my domain which results in 404 on the ingress side.

Comment: With the `curl` I receive a 308 status code which curl fails to follow even with `-L` flag

Comment: I wonder if this is because of the `app.mydomain.com` section.  Try defining your ingress with a different hostname, e.g `app2.mydomain.com` and test with curl again.  The issue could be dns resolution related?

Comment: I have already tried with different domain names :/

Comment: Also, How did you set up your load balancer for the ingress as a L7 load balancer? The default NLB is layer 4 so that's a bit confusing :S

Comment: the ingress controler config comes with options to configure either as L4 or L7, we went with the L7 config.  It's beem a while since I set it up, and we're running a very old version, so it's quite possible that things have changed :/